# Making a delete DAO -> Uncaught exception 'PDOException'

Tags: sql, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a dao which can delete a specific item once you click on the X

How did I try this? I'll begin with showing you the DAO:

```
public function delete($iddelete){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `wanthave`.`wanthave_items` WHERE `wanthave_items`.`id` = `iddelete` = :iddelete LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':iddelete', $iddelete);
    $stmt->execute();
    return  $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

This is how I setup my if structure in a controller:

```
    if(isset($_GET['iddelete'])){
        $this->itemDAO->delete($_GET['iddelete']);
    }
```

Once I click on the X near the item I want to delete it goes to a page with in the end "&iddelete=(id of the item)". So actually when iddelete is set it's going to delete it.

But unfortunately I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'iddelete' in 'where clause'' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wanthave/dao/ItemDAO.php:56 Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wanthave/dao/ItemDAO.php(56): PDO->prepare('DELETE FROM `wa...')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wanthave/controller/ItemController.php(198): ItemDAO->delete('89')
#2 [internal function]: ItemController->delete()
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wanthave/controller/Controller.php(9): call_user_func(Array) #4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wanthave/index.php(69): Controller->filter()
#5 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wanthave/dao/ItemDAO.php on line 56
```

Line 56 = $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

Any help?

Comment: what's unclear with error message?

Comment: `= iddelete =` - what's this?

Comment: what you are trying to fetch from DELETE statement?

Comment: OH I should've removed the 'iddelete' and the Fetch. Now everything works, okay thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function delete($id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM wanthave_items WHERE id = ?");
    return $stmt->execute([$id]);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: OMG. @TomaszKowalczyk I told you many times already - keep your hands off questions you don't understand.

Comment: Many times? Like where exactly? Also if you told me many times that, you've probably at least once heard from me that "if you're answering question by code sample at least explain what it does and why it fixes asker's problem".

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk it doesn't matter. If you have no idea of either  question and answer - move on. Go guard something else.

Comment: @Your Common Sense: Yes it does. I perfectly understand what is going on here, but still your answer isn't helping anyone apart the asker so it's useless for the broad audience.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk your vote remained alone. And it never gets more. Nobody surprised. So, what was all that scene about then? this was not a real question from the begginning. I helped that poor fella in comments and then just illustrated with the code. Now you come with pointless comments. What is your goal? What you are trying to achieve with this behavior? Make site cleaner? You failed. What else?